# One activity and multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

This is not really a problem but I just want to know am I using a good approach? 
I am developing an application, and in that app I am using fragments. Only one activity and multiple fragments. The thing is, my activity is not a `FragmentActivity`  because I've some views "Controls" on that activity. In the mid of the activity layout I am replacing fragments. Mock up UI is shown below.

[image: Mock up UI]

So the approach I am using is that I have a public method in my main activity `loadFragment(String fragment)`, I call this method from any fragment to load a particular fragment. I get instance of my activity and call this method like this.

```
MainActivity.getInstance().laodFragment(framgnet);
```

Instance is basically this.

```
private MainActivity instance;
```

And

```
public static MainActivity getInstance(){
     return instance;
}
```

Here my  `loadFragment()` method.

```
public void loadFragment(String fragment) {

        CURRENT_FRAGMENT = fragment;

        switch (fragment) {
            case FRAGMENT_WORK:
                generalFragment = new WorkFragment();
                break;
            case FRAGMENT_WORK_TWO:
                generalFragment = new WorkTwoFragment();
                break;
            case FRAGMENT_REGISTRATION:
                generalFragment = new RegistrationFragment();
                break;
            case FRAGMENT_INTERNAL:
                generalFragment = new InternalFragment();
                break;
            case FRAGMENT_ABSENCE:
                generalFragment = new AbsenceFragment();
                break;
            case FRAGMENT_OVERTIME:
                generalFragment = new OvertimeFragment();
                break;
            case FRAGMENT_HOME:
                clearAllFragments();
                generalFragment = new HomeFragment();
        }
        replaceFragment(generalFragment);
    }
```

I just want to know am I using a good approach? if not how can I improve it? 
I've already read that saving contexts in static variables is not a good approach.
Thank you.

Comment: Your method `loadFragment()` is is called a [factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).. Searching the internet for "factory pattern" might find the answer you are looking for

Comment: Yes I know what a factory method is but that doesn't give me the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> I've already read that saving contexts in static variables is not a
>   good approach

Correct ! `static` mostly good for cache.

You can  perform another alternative to make it tightly coupled like below.

**1:** Make an `Interface` to bridge-up `Activity` and `Fragment`.

```
interface BridgeInteface 
{
 public void loadFragment(String fragment); 
}
```

**2:** Implement that Interface to your `MainActivity`and `Override` method `loadFragment(String fragment)`

**3:** Pass the instance of Interface as parameter into the `Fragment`

```
    @Override
    public void loadFragment(String fragment) {

        CURRENT_FRAGMENT = fragment;

        switch (fragment) {
            case FRAGMENT_WORK:
                generalFragment = new WorkFragment(bridgeInteface);
                break;
            case FRAGMENT_WORK_TWO:
                generalFragment = new WorkTwoFragment(bridgeInteface);
                break;
            case FRAGMENT_REGISTRATION:
                generalFragment = new RegistrationFragment(bridgeInteface);
                break;
            case FRAGMENT_INTERNAL:
                generalFragment = new InternalFragment(bridgeInteface);
                break;
            case FRAGMENT_ABSENCE:
                generalFragment = new AbsenceFragment(bridgeInteface);
                break;
            case FRAGMENT_OVERTIME:
                generalFragment = new OvertimeFragment(bridgeInteface);
                break;
            case FRAGMENT_HOME:
                clearAllFragments();
                generalFragment = new HomeFragment(bridgeInteface);
        }
        replaceFragment(generalFragment);
    }
```

**4:** Call method `loadFragment(String fragment)` from your `Fragment` when you need to replace `Fragment`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But do you know overloading default constructor of a fragment is not recommended. Lets say I follow this approach, I launch a fragment and then another, when I'll hit the back button, my fragment will be recreated and android will automatically call default constructor. 
So this is not an effective solution.

Comment: I thought you wanted to replace the  Fragment by seeing  replaceFragment(generalFragment) method . And in that case you dont need to handle back stack .

Comment: No thats not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the solution to my problem. I removed all static instances from my `Fragments` and `Activity` and replaced all method calls with Event Calls. I used [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) library for this purpose. And it is extremely useful and easy to use.

Comment: It is always good to use a Event Bus like Otto. GreenRobot Eventbus is also very good. NEVER make use of static instances of Activities...it is very bad practice for several reasons.

Comment: Yes because of those reasons I posted this question.